# Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=128m' while deploying Gradle/Kotlin API to Heroku

Tags: kotlin, gradle, heroku

I have a Kotlin RESTful API hosted in Heroku. It runs normally with Java 11.

I added a `system.properties` file with:

```
java.runtime.version=17
```

My `build.gradle.kts` file has:

```
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

// Dependencies, other tasks, settings, etc.

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

When I try to push the app to Heroku, I have:

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/gradle
remote: -----> Gradle app detected
remote: -----> Spring Boot detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 17... done
remote: -----> Building Gradle app...
remote: -----> executing ./gradlew build -x check
remote:        Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=128m'
remote:        Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
remote:        Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

What exactly I'm missing here? `MaxPermSize` is not defined anywhere in the project.